# Detect if www subdomain is present

Tags: php, http, web

I want to detect if users who enter my site have entered the `www` subdomain, which most wont, and in such case redirect them to `www`. Basically if a user enters `mysite.com` I need to redirect them to `www.mysite.com` but I don't see how this can be detected with PHP only? My `$_SERVER` array doesn't contain such information. Is this possible at all?

Comment: You can do it by your web-server (like apache's htaccess or ngnix

Comment: @JohnConde but this is the opposite of what I'm trying to do :/

Comment: Is this about `Apache` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera yes, I can use .htaccess but not really good at it

Comment: @php_nub_qq You can't use that as a guide to do what you want? It definitely tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worse solution is to do it with PHP:

```
if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
  header('Location: http://www.' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
  exit();
}
```

Better from performance point of view solution with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this using `Apache` mod rewrite (put it in `.htaccess` file)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Please forgive me for I am going to accept Sanja's answer but I believe he will enjoy 15 rep more than you will at this point.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, if it makes you happy, I don't mind at all :-)